# How to submit MFCCs to the input algorithm?

Tags: mfcc, gmm

I want to train the GMM with the help of MFCC.

I have 588 audio files (wav, if it's important). After extracting the features, I get a set of 588 two-dimensional arrays (13x?). Each file has a different number of columns.

And how to submit MFCCs to the input algorithm?

Answer (score 0):

You can compute the length of columns. Make the longest one as reference.
Then traverse the mfccs.
If the number of columns is smaller the the reference,Pad the mfccs with zeros.
After doing that, the mfccs are in same shape. Then the mfccs can be fed to the model.